# How to create Push notification server from scratch

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, server

I use the gcm for getting the notifications, we say that there are so many applications that make use of this system of google, if the system was a day locked? or google decides to delete it or put it in payment? My intention is to know if I could create me a personal server that does the same things the GCM, there is some kind of open source project? That is to have a personal server that handles notifications without having to go to google.
is conceivable such a thing or is utopia?

Comment: Detailed GCM server implementation guide: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html  

Why don't you try Amazon SNS service, which provides Push notification service for both Android & iOS devices. http://aws.amazon.com/sns/

Comment: @AkashShende looking at the documentation I see that Amazon wants the step of a project ID_sender the google api. What sense to use a paid service (AMAZON) to have the same service (GOOGLE) but for a fee?

Answer (score 0):

GCM is well integrated with your Android application. In addition, GCM is a highly reliable and available messaging infrastructure that powers many Android devices worldwide. Many highly popular apps rely on GCM for push notifications and message delivery.

Also to note, even with GCM, you still need to create your own server to send messages to your GCM enabled Android application.

You can visit the [GCM architecture page](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#arch) for more information.